# "Recover" triangle from projection

Tags: geometry, linear-transformations

I have a triangle whose vertex coordinates are known. This triangle gets projected onto the *xOy* plane and its projection is a right isosceles triangle. For simplicity, let's say the coordinates of the projection are `(0, 0, 0)`, `(a, 0, 0)`, `(0, a, 0)` and the coordinates of the original triangle has coordinates `(0, 0, z0)`, `(a, 0, z1)`, `(0, a, z2)`. All these coordinates are known.

What transformations do I need to apply to get the original triangle from the projection?

I can translate the projection up until the middle of its hypotenuse coincides with the middle of its original edge, whose angle with the *xOy* plane I can compute knowing the vertex coordinates, so I can then rotate the translated projection and make this one edge's direction coincide with that of the original edge. And then? I'm stuck here.

Comment: In general you cannot recover the original triangle. If, for example, you subtract $(0,0,z_0)$ from the other original two coordinates, this new traingle will project to the right angled triangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a point $(x,y,0)$ in the projected triangle,

then the corresponding point in the original triangle is $$\left(x,y,x\frac{z_1-z_0}{a}+y\frac{z_2-z_0}{a}+z_0\right)$$

If the positive $z$-axis is *up*, then you are

- moving the projected triangle up by $z_0$ to get $(0,0,0)$ to $(0,0,z_0)$
- then stretching up proportionately to $x$ to get what is now $(a,0,z_0)$ to $(a,0,z_1)$
- then stretching up proportionately to $y$ to get what is now $(0,a,z_0)$, as it was unaffected by the first stretch, to $(0,a,z_2)$

and all the other points in the triangle will move as they should to retain their relationship with the vertices